# spring-boot restricted url

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

Good day,
I have a spring-boot 1.1.4.RELEASE app,that is using spring-security included as dependencies such as:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")    
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.1.RELEASE')
```

I have two types of roles: "User" and "Admin".  The latter has everything the former, but also access to an administration screen.  In my Thymeleaf page, I only display that link to users with an Admin role via, which works just fine:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    <i class="fa fa-link"></i><a th:href="@{/admin}">
            Administer User</a>
</li>
```

However, if I manually type in the url to that page (`http://localhost:9001/admin`), all roles can access it.  I thought i was controlling this via the Security Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/" ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/").hasRole("ADMIN")  <== also tried .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers( "/resources/**" ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/css/**" ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/libs/**" ).permitAll();

        http
                .formLogin().failureUrl( "/login?error" )
                .defaultSuccessUrl( "/" )
                .loginPage( "/login" )
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/logout" ) ).logoutSuccessUrl( "/" )
                .permitAll();

        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions( 1 )
                .expiredUrl( "/login?expired" )
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin( true )
                .and()
                .sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED )
                .invalidSessionUrl( "/" );

        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService( customUserDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( encoder );
    }
```

}

Is there something missing or incorrect in my configuration?

**Update**:
The solution I used, based upon Dave's answer was to use the following three lines:

```
.antMatchers( "/admin**" ).hasAuthority("ADMIN" )
.antMatchers( "/admin/" ).hasAuthority( "ADMIN" )
.antMatchers( "/admin/**" ).hasAuthority( "ADMIN" )
```

This will render a 403 error on the browser.  Eventually I will try and get it to redirect to either an error page or "/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only explicitly protected "/admin/" (with a trailing slash). I imagine you need to be more precise than that if you are visiting "/admin" (without a trailing slash).

Comment: Thank you Dave.  I actually had to add the following two lines so that the page isn't rendered:  .antMatchers( "/admin**" ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )  &&  .antMatchers( "/admin/**" ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )  otherwise, the "/admin/ url would render