# Spring Boot Security - Open access for / with restricted /admin access?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

So i have a simple spring boot app with out-of-the-box security configuration. In my 'dev' profile I've open access to all URLS with these properties

```
# dev
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

and I can enable authentication for all URL's in my 'production' profile by changing the values to

```
# production
security.basic.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=true
```

The real security requirement for the application is that it has two pages

1. The '/' index page should be public to all.
2. The '/admin' page should be restricted.

I know from countless [other stackoverflow questions in spring-boot-security and spring-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014489/spring-boot-restricted-url) that I can override the default spring-boot security config by using the @EnableWebSecurity and then defining custom rules

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()....

}
```

I'm wondering is there not a simpler way which configures spring-boot only, and which doesn't involve the customisation of the spring-security to achieve this requirement?

Comment: How can you say that you are customizing security api when you are only extending security it? Sorry to say but it doesn't make sense to me. This is the simplest way Spring Security is providing.

Comment: You don't need to reconfigure Spring Security. Just add an additional `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` extension, annotate it with `@Configuration` and that should  pick it up and let you extend the security rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between overriding and configuring. By using `@EnableWebSecurity`, you're still just configuring Spring Security to work the way you want it to work. So to answer your question, no, there is not a "simpler way". This is how you do it and it isn't difficult.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Something like that is more or less all you need based on your requirements.